# How to add parent to "parentless" tasks in DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am very new in DevOps, and I need to add a parent to parentless tasks in DevOps. I used a third-party tool to upload the user stories and tasks, and I think this is were it went wrong. When I click on a user story, I can see the tasks linked as children - but my coworkers keeps getting them on their boards as parentless. Any good fixes for this?

Looked online, didnt find any suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have Teams set up in ADO, and your coworkers aren't part of the team the parent story is set to (its iteration path). I would check with Team(s) your coworkers are members of, and check which iterations they are able to see on their backlog & boards.

You can easily bulk-update the iteration path on the tasks and stories from a query, or from the backlog view under which they are set.